# Android/FireStore Querying and returning a custom Object

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've got another question about Firestore and the Android/ Java Implementation but this time with the code. This is how my Database looks like: 
 
[image]

It's going to be a QuizApp, the Database contains a generated `ID` and a `customObject(type: questionDataObject name: content)` Also it has an Array List with following restrictions/thoughts: 
[0]: Question 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZxQA.jpg): Correct Answer 
[2]...[4] Wrong Answer 
I added an String "number" to the questionDataObject just to have something easy I can search/query for. And that is my problem, I can't get the query working.

```
    public class questionAdder extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText pQuestion, pAnwerA, pAnswerB, pAnswerC, pAnswerD, number;
    Button pAdd, query;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addquestion);

        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        pQuestion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question);
        pAnwerA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerA);
        pAnswerB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerB);
        pAnswerC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerC);
        pAnswerD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerD);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);

        pAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addQuestion);
        pAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                readQuestionStore();
            }
        });

        query = (Button) findViewById(R.id.query);
        query.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CollectionReference questionRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("questions");
                com.google.firebase.firestore.Query query = questionRef.whereEqualTo("content.number", "20");
                query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        //questionObject content = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(questionObject.class);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void readQuestionStore(){
        ArrayList<String> pContent = new ArrayList<>();
        pContent.add(0, pQuestion.getText().toString());
        pContent.add(1, pAnwerA.getText().toString());
        pContent.add(2, pAnswerB.getText().toString());
        pContent.add(3, pAnswerC.getText().toString());
        pContent.add(4, pAnswerD.getText().toString());
        questionObject content = new questionObject(pContent, number.getText().toString()); //document("Essen").collection("Katalog")
       firebaseFirestore.collection("questions").add(content).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                Toast.makeText(questionAdder.this, "Klappt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(questionAdder.this, "Klappt nicht", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class questionObject{
    private ArrayList<String> content;
    private String number;

    public questionObject(){

    }

    public questionObject(ArrayList<String> pContent, String pNumber) {
        this.content = pContent;
        this.number = pNumber;
    }

        public ArrayList<String> getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(ArrayList<String> content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

This App is nothing I want to publish, I just want to practice the Firebase Firestore coding etc. 

**Problem:** How can I get the Object from the database and how can I check if the query was successfull? I actually can not see if the query found my entry. The only feedback I have is that the cloud engine adds a "read". 
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I suggest you going through this [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), which will guide you about getting data from a `Cloud Firestore` database.

If you'll skip over to the ***Custom Objects*** part, you'll see the following piece of code:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ");
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        City city = documentSnapshot.toObject(City.class);
    }
});
```

This is how you can cast the `document snapshot` you received to a `custom object`. In your cast, you need to change the `City.class` to your object, which is `questionObject.class`.

---

In addition, you can't use an `Array List` as a property in your `custom object`, because the `Firebase module` won't be able to read that. Instead, you'll have to use a `Map` object. [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) is the Map object - a collection which has a `key` and a `value`, just like the `field name` and `value` in a `Firestore` `document`.

You can see in the Firestore documentation above, that under the ***Example Data*** part they have showed a `Map` example:

```
Map<String, Object> data1 = new HashMap<>();
data1.put("name", "San Francisco");
data1.put("state", "CA");
data1.put("country", "USA");
data1.put("capital", false);
data1.put("population", 860000);
```

That's why your `content` property should look like this:

```
Map<Integer, Object> content = new HashMap<>();
content.put(0, "a");
content.put(1, "a");
content.put(2, "a");
content.put(3, "a");
```

---

Furthermore, you can combine your `Query` and your `Get request` to one line of code:

```
CollectionReference questionRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("questions");
questionRef.whereEqualTo("content.number", "20").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I have found that part about getting data but I am unsure how I can combine the query with it. I‘ve got that code in the On Click listener for the Button query, would that be theoretically correct? I crossed out the .toObject Part as I indeed received an ArrayList incompatible Error. I‘m going to delete the array and add an hashmap as First step!

Comment: Yes, putting your listener in an `OnClickListener` is one option. It can also be in a separated `method` if there is more code  to be executed. Make sure you are showing a progress bar when the requests begins, and you are disabling it when it finishes, for the user to know its status.

Comment: Oh sorry I described it wrong. I wanted to ask if the query and get command in that OnClickListener is correct. The Firebase documentation only describes Get Only Or Query Only Examples, but I want to Query and Get. Sorry I am Not a native speaker I hope I could describe it better now.

Comment: @J.Lo I have edited my answer and added the combined edition of the Query and the Get. I hope it answers your question. You can put it in your `OnClickListener`.

Comment: I now changed the questionObject, it gets the number and a HashMap. I also edited the Query-Button-OnClickListenor but when trying to convert the Snapchot to my Object: questionObject pContent = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(questionObject.class); it gives me an incompatible types Error. Found java.util.list and Required: questionObject.

Comment: @J.Lo I think that a new question with your new code would be better for us to understand your problem and help. This question already has an answer, and it's hard to understand  what went wrong from your comment.